# MATLAB stop program after X repetitions?

Tags: matlab, terminate, trial, repeat

I have this program, which as you can see is pulling random pictures out of a directory, and asking the user to compare them. After setting the value with the slider, the user presses a "Next Trial" button, which resets the slider and the random picture pair. How do I modify the code so that, after a certain number of repetitions (button presses), the program automatically ends (preferably with a "Experiment Ended" message)?

I can't find anything about how to do this in the MATLAB documentation. Do I need to set a variable, so that everytime the button is pressed "1" is added to the value of the variable, so that when it reaches a certain number (say "100") it terminates? Is that the easiest way to do this?

Here's the script:

```
function trials

files = dir(fullfile('samples','*.png'));
nFiles = numel(files);
combos = nchoosek(1:nFiles, 2);
index = combos(randperm(size(combos, 1)), :);
picture1 = files(index(1)).name;
picture2 = files(index(2)).name;
image1 = fullfile('samples',picture1);
image2 = fullfile('samples',picture2);
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(image1);
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(image2);

uicontrol('Style', 'text',...
        'Position', [200 375 200 20],...
        'String','How related are these pictures?');
uicontrol('Style', 'text',...
        'Position', [50 375 100 20],...
        'String','Unrelated');
uicontrol('Style', 'text',...
        'Position', [450 375 100 20],...
        'String','Closely related');
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Next Trial',...
        'Position', [250 45 100 20],...
        'Callback','clf; trials()');

h = uicontrol(gcf,...
   'Style','slider',...
   'Min' ,0,'Max',50, ...
   'Position',[100 350 400 20], ...
   'Value', 25,...
   'SliderStep',[0.02 0.1], ...
   'BackgroundColor',[0.8,0.8,0.8]);

set(gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @cb);

lastVal = get(h, 'Value'); 

function cb(s,e)
    if get(h, 'Value') ~= lastVal 
    lastVal = get(h, 'Value'); 
    fprintf('Slider value: %f\n', lastVal); 
    end
end

end
```

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement [Hot or Not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_or_Not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I see here is that the callback for your "Next Trial" button simply calls the function `trials` again. This is going to generate the combinations of images again, which you only want/need to do once. You should set the callback to be another nested function (like `cb`) so it can access the already-generated combinations.

Another problem is how you initialize `picture1` and `picture2`. You should do your indexing like so:

```
picture1 = files(index(1,1)).name;  %# Note that index is 2-dimensional!
picture2 = files(index(1,2)).name;
```

Now, you'll first want to initialize a variable to track the number of trials inside the function `trials`, as well as a maximum number of trials:

```
nReps = 1;
maxReps = 100;
```

Then your "Next Trial" button callback would look something like this:

```
function newTrial(s, e)
    %# I assume you need the slider value for each trial, so fetch it
    %#   and save/store it here.

    %# Check the number of trials:
    if (nReps == maxReps)
        close(gcf);  %# Close the figure window
    else
        nReps = nReps + 1;
    end

    %# Get the new images:
    picture1 = files(index(nReps, 1)).name;
    picture2 = files(index(nReps, 2)).name;
    image1 = fullfile('samples', picture1);
    image2 = fullfile('samples', picture2);

    %# Plot the new images:
    subplot(1,2,1);
    imshow(image1);
    subplot(1,2,2);
    imshow(image2);

    %# Reset the slider to the default value:
    set(h, 'Value', 25);
end
```

One additional suggestion... instead of displaying the slider value on the screen using [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html), I would create a text object in your GUI and simply update its string value:

```
hText = uicontrol('Style', 'text', ...
                  'String', 'Slider value: 25', ... );

%# And in function cb...
set(hText, 'String', sprintf('Slider value: %f', lastVal));
```

Comment: Thanks! (I actually changed the slider value part already, I accidentally posted an older version of my code, heh). Anyway, great suggestions, I will see how they work.